Can my 'auto-add rows' formula be updated to copy data?
I was given the below formula, which has been really helpful:
Is there a formula capable of building rows in google sheets?
But I'd like to edit the formula so that when the data splits out into separate rows, it also copies across additional data in other columns. Is this possible?
Please see here for example


This is certainly possible using Excel Formulas as well Power Query:

• Using Formulas applicable to MS365
=LET(
     a, A3:D3, 
     b, SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)), 
     DROP(REDUCE("",b,LAMBDA(r,c,VSTACK(r,CHOOSECOLS(IF({1,1,1,0},
     INDEX(A3:D3,c,{1,3,4}),TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(A3:D3,c,2),,{", "," & "})),1,4,2,3)))),1)


• Using Power Query


let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    Replace = Table.ReplaceValue(Source," &",",",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column2"}),
    Split = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Replace, {{"Column2", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column2")
in
    Split




